# Issue getting overlay to cover an image

Tags: html, css

I cannot figure out why my `overlay` class is not producing the opacity overlay on top of the image. When viewing this in with the developer tools open the overlay box looks as if it is only covering the bottom 5% (just over the word "solutions"), however the link works anywhere on the image.

Does anyone see why my overlay isn't covering the entire image?

```css
.machInfo25 {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 height: 30vh;
 position: relative;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.overlay {
 position: relative;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 border: none;
  z-index: 3;
}
.machInfo25 {
 width: 25%;
}
.machInfo25 img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
}
a .machineInfoTitle {
 color: #FFF;
}
.total-center {
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="machInfo25">
  <a class="overlay" href="solutions">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQqXxLsqFCFPx0l_3_h5sn-0JN2oU5GU-wGnHH3CbJLSMeywV6CLA" alt="View all">
    <div class="total-center">
      <span class="machInfoTitle">Solutions</span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display: block;` or `display: inline-block` to your overlay class. `<a>` elements are inline elements which size differently than block elements. The link is still working on the entire image since the image is a child of the link

```css
.machInfo25 {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 height: 30vh;
 position: relative;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.overlay {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  border: none;
  /*z-index: 3;*/
}

.machInfo25 {
 width: 25%;
}

.machInfo25 img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
}

a .machineInfoTitle {
 color: #FFF;
}

.total-center {
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="machInfo25">
  <a class="overlay" href="solutions">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQqXxLsqFCFPx0l_3_h5sn-0JN2oU5GU-wGnHH3CbJLSMeywV6CLA" alt="View all">
    <div class="total-center">
      <span class="machInfoTitle">Solutions</span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: + .machInfo25 img {position: relative; z-index: -1} + comment out the .overlay's z-index

Answer (score 0):

Here I have added a sample code, Hope, this will help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
            .container {
              position: relative;
              width: 50%;
            }

            .image {
              display: block;
              width: 100%;
              height: auto;
            }

            .overlay {
              position: absolute;
              top: 0;
              bottom: 0;
              left: 0;
              right: 0;
              height: 100%;
              width: 100%;
              opacity: 0;
              transition: .5s ease;
              background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
            }

            .container:hover .overlay {
              opacity: 1;
            }

            .text {
              color: white;
              font-size: 20px;
              position: absolute;
              top: 50%;
              left: 50%;
              -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
              -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
              transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
              text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQqXxLsqFCFPx0l_3_h5sn-0JN2oU5GU-wGnHH3CbJLSMeywV6CLA" alt="View all" class="image">
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="text">Solutions</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The background of `.overlay` was under the image. I applied the black transparency to the [pseudo-code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) of class `.overlay`.

```css
.machInfo25 {
  height: 30vh;
  width: 25%;
}

.overlay {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.overlay:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.machInfo25 img {
  width: 100%;
}

a .machInfoTitle {
  color: white;
}

.total-center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="machInfo25">
  <a class="overlay" href="solutions">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQqXxLsqFCFPx0l_3_h5sn-0JN2oU5GU-wGnHH3CbJLSMeywV6CLA" alt="View all">
    <div class="total-center">
      <span class="machInfoTitle">Solutions</span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```